# AddEVentListener not working after updated html button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
<!-- Any html blocks -->
{% for n in loop %}
<div class="update">
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="update--btn">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}


let updateBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('update--btn');

[...updateBtn].forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', clickBtn);
})

function clickBtn() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.onload = () => {
        let cartUpdate = this.closest('.update');
        cartUpdate.innerHTML ='';

        let cartUpdateInner = document.createElement('div');
        cartUpdateInner.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="update--btn">+</button>'
        cartUpdate.appendChild(cartUpdateInner);
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

When the page is loaded for the first time, all working. But second click on button, after change HTML in  not working.

PS. I need change html, not only text

Comment: Aren't you just deleting the content with `cartUpdate.innerHTML ='';`?

Comment: You should either use some form of [event delegation](https://dev.to/js_bits_bill/event-delegation-with-vanilla-js-js-bits-2lnb) or reapply the event listener after you recreate the button.

Comment: @NakarukatoshiUzumaki Yes

Comment: @Shikkediel Can you show any example for `reapply the event listener`, please?

Comment: @Shikkediel Sorry, but if addEventListener put inside clickBtn and xhr, addEventListener not will working

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? https://jsfiddle.net/1r6uf5z4/

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/5yuo9wmc/) is how you'd approach a delegated event. Which is cleaner anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your update button code in a function like

```
function addevent(){
[...updateBtn].forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener('click', clickBtn);
})
}
```

and then call it on page load for first time

```
window.onload = addevent;
```

and then you need to reassign this event after adding new buttons so you can call this in the end of your clickBtn function

```
addevent()
```